# Prolog XPCE: Text Labels for Connections

Tags: prolog, label, swi-prolog, connection, xpce

In XPCE, graphical objects can be connected with the Connection class (see Chapter 5.3. in the [manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/xpce/doc/userguide/userguide.pdf)).

Is there an easy way to attach text labels to connections?

Answer (score 2):

Positioning the label with XPCE constraints (https://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/xpce/UserGuide/sec-5.4.html), perhaps with help of class spatial (https://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/xpce/UserGuide/summary.html#class:spatial) ?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that and to have a built-in solution for that. 

The remark "Constraints are getting out of fashion as XPCE lacks a good mechanism to detect when an object has been changed and therefore evaluates the relation far too often" does not sound very appealing to me either. *Sigh*.

I guess I'll try constraints, or find an alternative to labeled edges.